# Sibling project seems not using it's dependency's build.gradle script

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have multi-module project with a structure like this:

```
|fullstack
\backend
 |build.gradle
\frontend
 |build.gradle
|build.gradle
|settings.gradle
```

Settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'fullstack'
include 'backend'
include 'frontend'
```

`backend` depends on `ktor`, so it's `build.gradle` contains repository:

```
maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
```

And `backend` module builds well.

Then I want to share some common classes between backend and frontend. I could make third module `api` and make others depend on it. But now I want to avoid third module and just make `frontend` to depend on `backend`.
I added the dependency to the `frontend`'s `gradle.build`:

```
compile project (':backend')
```

and tried to build the whole project, but got an error:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':frontend:compileClasspath'.
>
> > Could not find io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:0.9.1.   Searched in the following locations:
> >           https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/ktor/ktor-server-netty/0.9.1/ktor-server-netty-0.9.1.pom
> >           https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/ktor/ktor-server-netty/0.9.1/ktor-server-netty-0.9.1.jar
> >     Required by:
> >           project :frontend > project :backend

It obviously didn't scan repositories of `backend` module. Why?

**UPDATE**
I've added repositories as said in answers. But when I try to import in `frontend/main.kt` any class from `backend` I get:

> :frontend:compileKotlin2Jse: D:\...\frontend\src\main\kotlin\main.kt: (1, 8): Unresolved reference: com
>   e: D:\...\frontend\src\main\kotlin\main.kt: (2, 8): Unresolved reference: com

How to make it visible for `frontend`?

Root `build.gradle`:

```
group 'com.norg.parts'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_ver = '1.2.50'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_ver"
    }
}

allprojects {
    project.ext {
        kotlin_version = kotlin_ver
        ktor_version = '0.9.1'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx' }
        maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifac/' }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed" }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.norg.parts.MainKt'
    }
//TODO    include jar from frontend!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there can be 2 `dependencies` / `repositories` blocks. The first one is in the `buildscript` which looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}
```

This is responsible for setting up **tooling** and **plugins**. Then when you set up the config of your **project** itself you can do several things. If you don't have a multi-module project you just dump it into your `build.gradle` then the file looks like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version"
}
```

In your case you should use either `allprojects` which means that all configuration which you put in that block will be applied to all your projects (including root), or `subprojects`. In the latter case, the block will be applied to only your subprojects (root not included). This looks like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

subprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version"
    }
}
```

Your problem is that you did not add the repository itself to your **project** config, only your `buildscript` config.

If you are planning to mix frontend and backend code you can now use Kotlin Multiplatform Projects. I've written about this [here](http://the-cogitator.com/2018/04/25/going-beyond-android-kotlin-on-the-frontend.html).

**Response to your edit:**

You really need to move all this to a `subprojects` block:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.norg.parts.MainKt'
        }
    //TODO    include jar from frontend!
    }
}
```

and you also need to add the `backend` project as a dependency to your `frontend` project in that project's `build.gradle`. I'd **strongly advise** you to read the [Gradle Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html) since this is a Gradle issue *not* a Kotlin issue whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks, but I always thought that mixing frontend and backend code is bad practice, isn't it?

Comment: Can I add anything to subprojects'/allprojects' `buildscript`?

Comment: No, `buildscript` is a singular thing and it is only for the build tools' and plugins' config. `allprojects` and `subprojects` are for the project(s) itself.

Comment: @ПавелКрижановский why would mixing them be a problem? Kotlin multiplatform projects are all about mixing them to great effect. Don't believe something because someone said so. Take a look and decide for yourself.

Comment: I have updated the question. Do I need multiplatform project to do what I want?

Comment: Can you show us how your *complete* `build.gradle` files look like?

Comment: `build.gradle` attached to question

Comment: Where do you have source files? Only in `backend` and `frontend`?

Comment: yes. And the problem now is that I can't import datamodel classes, declared in `backend`, into `frontend` (see the previous question update)

Comment: The problem is that you are not using `subprojects` nor `allprojects`

Comment: Section "allprojects { }" presents in the script. What do you mean?

Comment: I decided to remake the whole project in a multiplatform way. Now it works. Thank you for your article! Also this was helpful: https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/architecture-for-multiplatform-development-in-kotlin-cc770f4abdfd

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies are transitive, but repositories are not. This is why most projects have a `allprojects` block in the root build file defining the repositories for all subprojects at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. What about other `gradle.build`'s content? Does Gradle run tasks in it?

Comment: Gradle runs all build scripts, but their contents are context-sensitive. A task defined for one project won't affect another unless it is a dependency. Configuration is not shared. (`allprojects`/`subprojects` just applies the configuration to each project individually)